# How to get shadows working with ArCore Unity?

Tags: shadow

I don't want an object to cast a shadow.

I want a large object that is one piece to cast shadows into itself like a AO bake.

It works perfect if I use the USB instant preview, but when I do a build, there are no shadows to be seen.

What setting have I missed?

Again, I am not interested in just a drop shadow under a single object, but self shadowing from my directional light real-time or baked in from the light source.

Answer (score 0):

If the shadow looks okay when you're using the instant preview, it might be that the Android quality setting is set too low, causing it to not have shadows.

Go to Quality Settings and see what the default quality setting is for Android. Set it to something similar to Standalone.